# Proximal Operator / Mapping of Multiplication of Two Matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, proximal-operators

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $n \times n$. I am trying to find the proximal operator of the below functions i.e. assume one of the matrices constant while finding the $L1$ proximal operator of the other matrix $$ g(B) = |AB|_1 \quad f(A) = |AB|_1$$
where $L1$ norm of a matrix is the absolute sum of all the elements.
I am not able to find a way to solve the above problem. I would be really grateful if someone could give a pointer to it. There is a similar question [Finding analytically proximal operator of $g(P)=\|PX\|_1$ using Moreau decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878328/finding-analytically-proximal-operator-of-gp-px-1-using-moreau-decomposi?rq=1) , but I was not able to find the analytical solution to it.

Comment: It sounds contradictory to say "with respect to $A$ and $B$" then say "that is assume one of the matrices constant while finding the $L_1$ proximal operator of the other matrix". The function $g$ written here takes two matrices as input and is non-convex.

Comment: Indeed. If you want the proximal operator of $f(B) = \|AB\|_{\ell_1}$, say, just write it that way. Otherwise we convex nerds think you're trying to solve a non-convex optimization problem naïvely :-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant Made the changes which you suggested.

Comment: I think that there is not a nice formula for the prox-operator of $f$ or $g$. If there were, I think it would lead to simpler algorithms for optimization problems with $\ell_1$ regularization, such as total variation regularization or wavelet regularization, and that is something we would hear about a lot.

Comment: @littleO Do you think there is a solution through a computer analysis?

Comment: It could be evaluated using an iterative algorithm, but if you'd like to post the full optimization problem that you want to solve, there might be a better approach that avoids the need to evaluate this prox-operator entirely.

Comment: @littleO I am trying to solve https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2774197/l1-norm-constraint-on-product-of-2-matrix this problem

Comment: Indeed, one of the motivating factors for the creation of TFOCS was to handle cases like this where we had things like $\|Ax\|$ instead of just $\|x\|$, the former not admitting an analytic prox formula.